# How to enable Power View in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: 2013, powerpivot, performancepoint, business-intelligence

I use `SharePoint 2013` and `Performance Point Service` for create Business Intelligence report. But I need more functionality in report generation.

I found that `Power View` in this scenario can help me. How can I install and configure Power View in SharePoint 2013?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a good guide on TechNet that guides you through all the BI stack install on SharePoint 2013.

Basically what is needed is an SSRS install in SharePoint mode

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/96ce12ba-0ce1-40dd-94a3-0c7fcd7f9010